# Does GKZ's reflexivity theorem imply the Plucker formula?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, duality

Let $S\subset\mathbb{P}^n$, Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky defined its dual variety $S^\vee\subset\mathbb{P}^{n^\ast}$. In this paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0111179v1.pdf), the author obtained the general form of the classical Plucker formula:

$C_{S_1}\cdot C_{S_2}+\frac{(C_{S_1}\cdot\mathbb{P}^n)(C_{S_2}\cdot\mathbb{P}^n)}{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)}=C_{S_1^\vee}\cdot C_{S_2^\vee}+\frac{(C_{S_1^\vee}\cdot\mathbb{P}^{n^\ast})(C_{S_2^\vee}\cdot\mathbb{P}^{n^\ast})}{(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)},$

where $S_1,S_2\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ are projective varieties and $C_S\subset\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^{n^\ast}$ denotes the conormal variety of $S\subset\mathbb{P}^n$. From this he recovers the classical statement of the Plucker formula. Namely for every plane curve $S\subset\mathbb{P}^2$, we have

$\deg S^\vee=d(d-1)-2\delta-3\kappa$

for its dual curve $S^\vee\subset\mathbb{P}^{2^\ast}$, where $d,\delta,\kappa$ denote the degree, the number of nodes and the number of cusps respectively.

However, the **reflexivity theorem** due to GKZ implies that $C_S=C_{S^\vee}$, in this sense the above general form of the Plucker formula seems to be an identity. So GKZ's reflexivity theorem implies the Plucker formula?

Comment: The reflexivity theorem is not due to GKZ, it  is a very classical result, essentially due to Monge (a modern proof by Wallace goes back to 1956). I recommend the survey article by S. Kleiman *Tangency and duality*, CMS Conf. Proc. 6, AMS,
  pp. 163–225, for a detailed historical discussion.